# Javascript OnClick Button function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm trying to edit some code in order to execute a function once someone press on a button. For example, https://jsfiddle.net/h0eks0vq/12/

```js
/* Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction */
document.getElementById("buttons-services").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

/* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons-services">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton10" title="Cliquez pour une description du service offert" >Assemblage</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<p id="demo">
```

The problem that i'm having is that the text showed when the function is executed is always the same despite having some different text for the different buttons.

Comment: javascript is not java, you have an incorrect tag specification.

Comment: Please go learn HTML basics first. IDs _must_ be _unique_ within an HTML document.

Comment: There's no text (other than the button value) in your example. You need to provide a real [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- you assigned the same ID to multiple elements
- you assigned the function to the event before defining it
- you assigned the event handler in two places, i.e., the `onclick` attribute and the `addEventListener` function

and other minor mistakes. I've fixed some for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/h0eks0vq/18/

You'll notice, among other things, that I used classes to identify multiple elements, and that I introduced an attribute to indicate which popup should appear (uniquely identified by an ID). Keep in mind that the attribute name **must** start with `data-`.

Comment: Tyvm for your toughfull answer. Like many have said, I'm having a hard time understand those classes/Id thingy. Thank you for the fixes, I'm reviewing my previous code to understand what I did wrong. Ty